# How to setTimout on react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component which fetch data from backend. Here I have already added loading while the component fetch on data from backend. But the problem is if there is no data available there it still keeps on showing that loading. Instead I want to show something like `There is nothing In here` Text on screen if loading is complete and no data is available there. I want to know how to implement this any help would be great.

> This is my code

```
class FootStep extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getFootstep();
  }
  render() {
    const { loaded, loading, error, data } = this.props.footstep.data;
    console.log("footstepContainer props", this.props);
    if (loaded) {
      return <Footstep data={data} />;
    } else return <p>loading</p>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Add a separate flag into state for tracking the loading state; change this flag when data is loaded.

Comment: @raina77ow I am not getting you. I am using redux for state management here If state shows `loaded` then I render the `Footstep Component`

Comment: Where does the question talk about `setTimeout?` @adityakumar

Comment: Please change the title to `"Show No Results"  message when loading is completed on React component`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loaded should be true if response is successful and 
Check if the the length of data is zero then show message

```
    if(loaded && data.length === 0){
                   return <p>No Data available!</p>
          }
        else if (loaded) {
                  return <Footstep data={data} />;
                } 
            else 
    return <p>loading</p>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can we do something like this?

```
        if (loaded) {
          return <Footstep data={data} />;
        } else if(loaded && data.length === 0){
           return <p>No Data available!</p>
        } else return <p>loading</p>;
```